# Overwrite javascript reserved words on minify bundles Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, minify

I have the following code in javascript:

```
Array.prototype.any = function (test) {
    if (!arguments.length)
        return !!this.length;

    var arguments = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    var functionTest = typeof test == "function" ? test : function (x) {return x == test;};

    for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++)
        if (functionTest.apply(this[i], [this[i]].concat(arguments)))
            return true;

    return false;
};
```

When I used **Asp.net bundle to minify the JS file**, the reserved word "**arguments**" become a char variable like a letter "i", however I need the variable arguments because it has the parameters of function stored.

You can see after minify below:

```
Array.prototype.any=function(n){var i,r,t,u;if(!i.length)return!!this.length;for(i=Array.prototype.slice.call(i,1),r=typeof n=="function"?n:function(t){return t==n},t=0,u=this.length;t<u;t++)if(r.apply(this[t],[this[t]].concat(i)))return!0;return!1}
```

Somebody knows how can I prevent this change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think assigning arguments to arguments is a good idea :)

Remove `var arguments = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);` and replace it with `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);`.

Comment: Thank you, it resolved my problem.
I didn't know, but when I used a reserved word name like a variable, the minifier recognizes a reserved word like a variable local too and overwrites all reserved words in the context, causing the error.